# Ruby on Rails 5 on MacOS Sierra can't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos-sierra

I used rails by rvm gemset 2.3.1@rails500 on OSX el capitan is good.But when I update my MacOs to Sierra, I can't use 2.3.1@rails500 normally.

I encountered the problem like that when I create a model the command running will
stuck at ruby environment and stop at ruby environment:[image]

and console can't connect to my database.
The last information is

```
[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html
```

Is it only one solution that backing to el capitan ?

Comment: I had a similar problem when I updated to Sierra, and my solution was reinstalling all my ruby versions. Try reinstalling one version an see if the problem persist

Comment: @daniloisr I have reinstalled ruby 2.3.1 and rails 5.0.0.1, but the problem is not solved.

Comment: Can you provide the error message when you try to connect to your database?

Comment: @daniloisr I can't because it is over thousands line....

Comment: This is normal, there are many lines due all the execution stack. But you can take only a few (like the first 10 lines), they will probably have the reason. And you edit your question to add these lines, will help a lot to identify the problem.

Comment: @daniloisr I can't read first 10 lines, but the info in the end I have put it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126764/discussion-between-daniloisr-and-champer-wu).